# Does the increased travel pace from the Elk option for the Totem Warrior barbarian's Aspect of the Beast feature apply to combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, barbarian, travel

So I have been looking into the various 'Aspect's of the Beast' you get from the Totem Warrior Barbarians in 5e, as my own character is about to hit that level I am looking for clarification in regards to the rules associated with the wording for the 'Elk' aspect.

In the **Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, pg. 122** it states:

> **Elk.** Whether mounted or on foot, your travel pace is doubled, as is the travel pace of up to 10 companions while they’re within 60 feet of you and you’re not incapacitated (see chapter 8 in the Player’s Handbook for more information about travel pace). The elk spirit helps you roam far and fast.

And then referring to **Chapter 8: Adventuring, Pages 181-182** it states:

> While traveling, a group of adventurers can move at a normal, fast, or slow pace, as shown on the Travel Pace table. The table states how
>   far the party can move in a period of time and whether the pace has
>   any effect. A fast pace makes characters less perceptive, while a slow
>   pace makes it possible to sneak around and to search an area more
>   carefully (see the “Activity While Traveling” section later in this
>   chapter for more information).

Now does this increase movement also apply to in combat? I believe it does not but the term Travel could be interpreted into all movement.
Again I do not believe this to be the case as it would then make my 
character's movement in Combat 90ft without dashing or spells.

Comment: Related: [Does the Elk option for the Totem Warrior barbarian's Aspect of the Beast feature affect travel pace for land vehicles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164877/does-the-elk-option-for-the-totem-warrior-barbarians-aspect-of-the-beast-featur)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### It does not apply to combat.

The Elk Aspect specifically states "Travel Pace" (PHB. Pg. 182) not movement speed. This feature was intended to allow the party to travel quickly not perform swifter movements or actions during combat or other instances.

Also, if you refer to the activities you are able to perform while traveling (PHB Pg. 182) there is no such mention of combat, as you cannot perform combat while traveling, as this would cease traveling and initiate combat, in which case would cease the Elk Aspect of the Beast as you are no longer traveling.