# Can a Tabaxi's Feline Agility be used with the Haste spell's doubled speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monk, multi-classing, tabaxi

A friend of mine played a one-shot and they were all told to make 20th-level characters. He made an 18th level monk tabaxi with 2 levels in Rogue. He tried to make his character as fast as possible. My biggest concern was Feline Agility being paired with Haste (cast by his girlfriend's sorcerer character).

Let's start by breaking this down a bit.

The tabaxi is an 18th monk, so he gets a **+30 to his speed**, making his walking speed 60.

Then he took the mobile feat- **making his walking speed 70.**

If this tabaxi was affected by the ***Haste* spell** (see below) his walking speed would double, **so now it is 140.**

The **Haste** spell says (PHB, pg. 250):

> Until the spell ends, **the target's speed is doubled**, it gains a +2
>   bonus to AC, it has advantage on Dexterity saving throws and **it gains
>   an additional action on each of its turns**. That action can be used
>   only to take the Attack (one weapon Attack only), **Dash**, Disengage,
>   Hide, or Use an Object action.

The rogue's **Cunning Action** feature says:

> You can take a bonus action on each of your turns in combat. This action can be used only to take the **Dash**, Disengage, or Hide action.

So far, no problem... but now he wants to dash... three times.

140 (**Current base walking speed**) + 140 (**action** used to Dash) + 140 (**extra action from Haste**) + 140 (**bonus action** Dash from the rogue's **Cunning Action**) = **560 feet.**

And now he wants to use **Feline Agility** to make his total movement for the round **1120 feet**.

The tabaxi's Feline Agility trait says (*Volo's Guide to Monsters*, p. 115):

> When you move on your turn in combat, you can double your speed until
>   the end of the turn.

This feels extremely excessive (because I think that speed would be over 135 miles per hour), but usually, I care more about everyone having fun than being a rules lawyer. But I am curious:

**Can Feline Agility and *Haste's* doubling of speed stack?**

Comment: Hmm.  I smell cheese.  Nice, ripe cheese.

Comment: Related on [What is the fastest a character can move in one turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58632/what-is-the-fastest-a-character-can-move-in-one-turn). Question is closed, but relevant :)

Comment: I'd personally rule as letting it go if that's really what he built the character for. It sounds like he had good laughs at the table, awesome, yes. Useful? Questionable.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I think we might have already had this cheese before?

Comment: Not about Tabaxi, but somewhat related: [What is the lowest level at which a human can beat the 100m world record (or: the presumed human limit) without using magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159143)

Answer (score 21):

## It all stacks

You've quoted all the relevant bits so, as long as the character moves, their movement effectively with *haste* becomes 280.

They've heavily invested in this build, so let them squeeze as much out of it as they can! Moving that far may not be as helpful as they'd think in a constrained battlespace, but there may be times where it is relevant.

Comment: I'm not doubting, but do you have a source for saying that it stacks?

Comment: @neutralvax it's more that there isn't a source to show they don't.

Comment: The rule of "no hidden rules".  If one source says "+ speed", and another source says "+ speed", they stack, unless one source says "+ speed, but does not stack with speed from ....."

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of math here, but with a base walking speed of 70 feet, doubled by haste would be 140, then doubled by Feline Agility would be 280. So 280 movement, plus 280 Dash as an Action, plus 280 Dash as a Bonus Action, only adds up to 840 feet of movement. Not as excessively high as the 1120 feet of movement you calculated, but still very impressive.

Thanks to the correction by @NautArch: The additional Haste Action to Dash would be an additional 280, and would be the 1120 feet of movement. So yea, the math checks out. Nice.

Comment: You're missing the haste action dash.

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds that the question itself and the older answer didn't already cover.

Comment: It was just confirming the math, which before the edit, did not add up. After the edit, it was just additional confirmation. If I had not of forgotten the additional action provided by Haste, this answer would not have been added.